# Nested Case statement in shell script | Getting Syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to run below shell script but i am getting syntax error.

> script.sh env1 ManagedSvr1
>    line 29: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
>    line 30: **syntax error: u**nexpected end of file

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in "env1")
ssh  weblogic@hostname1 << EOF
    case "$server" in
    "ManagedSvr1")
            tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr1/logs/ManagedSvr1.log
    ;;
    "ManagedSvr2")
            tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr2.log
    ;;
    esac
;;
"env2")
    ssh  weblogic@hostname2 << EOF
    case "$server" in
    "ManagedSvr1")
            tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr1/logs/ManagedSvr1.log
    ;;
    "ManagedSvr2")
            tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr2.log
    ;;
    esac
;;
esac
```

Comment: As far as I can see you didn't terminate your HERE doc. I'll try to reproduce, but after your `esac` you need to terminate `EOF` before `;;`

Comment: If you're running the same `ssh` / `tailf` commands in each case, why do you duplicate them, instead of just set a variable inside the `case` statements, and use that variable unconditionally later? Also removes the need for a heredoc entirely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy's suggestion is the same as my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need `"HERE"` docs, per say, you're using one case statement which is taking standard input to your SSH command. take single quotes as input to `ssh` This lets you do multiline input in peace. Quoting your `"EOF"` and terminating it, is also acceptable usage.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in

"env1")

        ssh -tt weblogic@hostname1 <<< '
        case "$server" in
        "ManagedSvr1")
                cat /var/log/syslog
        ;;
        "ManagedSvr2")
                tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr2.log
        ;;
        esac '
        ;;
"env2")
        ssh -tt weblogic@hostname2 <<< '
        case "$server" in
        "ManagedSvr1")
                tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr1/logs/ManagedSvr1.log
        ;;
        "ManagedSvr2")
                tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr2.log
        ;;
        esac '
        ;;
esac
```

This would be an easier way to manage the script. Especially as you're not utilising remote user change: Lets you set all your variables locally, and then just connect and execute the single command.

```
#!/bin/bash

server="$2"
case "$1" in

"env1")
        hostname="hostname1"
        case "$server" in
        "ManagedSvr1")
                remote_command=$(tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr1.log)
        ;;
        "ManagedSvr2")
                remote_command=$(tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr2.log)
        ;;
        esac
        ;;
"env2")
        hostname="hostname2"
        case "$server" in
        "ManagedSvr1")
                remote_command=$(tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr1/logs/ManagedSvr1.log)
        ;;
        "ManagedSvr2")
                remote_command=$(tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr2/logs/ManagedSvr2.log)
        ;;
        esac
        ;;
*)
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then ssh weblogic@$hostname $remote_command
fi
```

Comment: doesn't that assume that `$server` is defined by default in the environment of the ssh command?  I think it's more likely to be defined from the calling script.  The single quotes are going to throw that off aren't they?

Comment: As per your comments i have taken single quotes but giving error : Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: @DanFarrell As OP hasn't mentioned it one can never assume. the afaik `${server}` is not defined by default on any system, so it would have to be an exported variable on the destination system (maybe?) or perhaps he's doing a prior `server=$(hostname -s)` but skipped for brevity?

Comment: Try `ssh -t -t` (or ssh -tt for short) to force pseudo-tty allocation even if stdin isn't a terminal.

Comment: Yes i am able to connect to remote server but my next case statement  (case "$server" in ) is  trying to run on remote server home path. :(

Comment: @Patils where do you define `$server` ?

Comment: My mistake .. i have added server=$2
export server;
and passing server as a parameter.

Comment: @Patils `export` will share variables outside of the script, but not outside of the server. Essentially we are executing code on the remote machine, which has no scope of variables defined outside of it. Is "ManagedSvr1" the hostname by any chance? e.g. if you `ssh` to the external server and type in `hostname -s`

Answer (score 2):

Your Here Docs specify EOF to end them (`<< EOF`) but you never have an EOF to end them.  Note that EOF doesn't mean End of File, it means the string 'EOF'.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document has examples.

I'm not sure what you're hoping to accomplish, but it looks to me that you need to specify which file to tail.   Are you hoping to pass the inner case into the remote shell on the server you're sshing into?  It would simplify your code to set your filename and servername first and then ssh and execute the command.  Actually, I don't see much purpose in your inner case statements anyway.  Instead of wrapping everything in the 'env' case, you could just set the hostname to a variable.  And then the "servername" can just be interpolated into the filesystem path.  something like this seems like a simple approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
env1)
  hostname="hostname1"
;;
env2)
  hostname="hostname2"
;;
esac
echo ssh weblogic@$hostname tailf  /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/$servername/logs/$servername.log
```

Seems to work simply and straight forward:

```
servername=ManagedSvr1 ./t.sh env1
ssh weblogic@hostname1 tailf /app/Oracle/Middleware/domains/dq/servers/ManagedSvr1/logs/ManagedSvr1.log
```

Take out the "echo" to actually execute the ssh.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your reply. The shell script is for tailing logs of  more than 2 remote server and i am passing env & managedserver name as a parameter